# Upcasting pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, upcasting

I have a doubt with upcasting with pointers in C++.

I'm going to write an example of my problem:

```
class A {}
class B : public A {}

A* pA = new A();
B* pB = new B();

pA = pB; //fails
pA = dynamic_cast<A*>(pB); //fails
```

I don't know what I'm missing. I think I don't understand at all the upcasting. Any help please? Thanks

UPDATED With the error:

```
[exec] ..\asdf\qwerty.cpp(123) : error C2681: 'B*' : invalid expression type for dynamic_cast
```

I have found how it works, like this:

```
pA* = (pA*)pB;
```

But I don't understand why.

EDIT: My editor is telling me that: "a value of type B* cannot be assigned to an entity of type A*". What does this mean?

To be more exactly, pB is being returned by a function. I don't know if it has something to do: is like this:

```
class C { 
    B* pB;
    B* getB() { return pB; }
}

A* pA;
pA = c.getB(); //this crashes. c was declared before... it is just an example
```

Comment: What do you mean "fails". Compiler error? This should work. Please show your full example along with any error messages.

Comment: http://ideone.com/dMjPsE works. What does your actual code look like ?

Comment: Please post a *complete* example that demonstrates your error. I.e. we should be able to copy, paste, hit compile, and see the *exact* same error message you post (assuming we use the same compiler of course - an equivalent message if not).

Comment: I think it is going to be because it's the result of a function call... check the last update please.

Comment: It is the most simple and obvious example of polymorphism. If it didn't work, C++ would not be an object oriented language.

Comment: -1 ... Instead of asking your question twice if it gets downvoted, improve your original question instead of just asking it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing semicolons `;` after class definitions:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
```

Also for `dynamic_cast` to return a meaningful result you need at least one virtual method in A. You need to have virtual destructor in a polymorphic base class for destruction to work correctly anyway:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual ~A() {}
};
```

Comment: The one about being a return of a function

Answer (score 3):

You are missing semicolons in your classes definition. Upcasting in C++ is totally legal and can be done in an implicit way (polymorphism). This works for me :

```
class A {

public:
  virtual ~A() {}
};

class B : public A {};

int     main()
{
  A* pA;
  B* pB = new B();

  pA = pB;
  delete pB;
  return (0);
}
```

Also, you should declare the destructor of `A` as `virtual` to avoid potential memory leaks. If you do not and try to delete the instance of `B`, the destructor of `A` will be called, but the destructor of `B` will not be called, leaving all the allocated resources held by `B` unfreed.

Comment: +one for explaining memory leaks

Answer (score 0):

no reason for   pA = pB;  not working, it should work, what do you mean by "fails"?
pointer upcast is trivial and can be used without dynamic casting.